# Grails integration test - redirect action returns null

Tags: unit-testing, grails, junit, integration-testing

This is a small integration `Junit` that I'm having difficulty with.  I've re-written this several different ways and the current way is straight out of the Grails manual - but it still returns `null`.  I don't see the error; I thought it might be a spelling error but I've checked all those.  I've tried `redirectUrl` and `redirectedUrl` - still returns `null`.

Controller snippet:

```
@Transactional(readOnly = true)     
def saveReportError() {
    redirect(action:'reportError')  
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
void "test save error report"() {
controller.saveReportError()
    assertEquals '/reportSiteErrors/reportError', controller.response.redirectUrl
}
```

Comment: I should also note that I've tried the path in the Assert statement several ways.  '/reportSiteErrors/reportError', '/reportError', and ''

Comment: Please provide further details such as Grails version. Why do you use an integration test instead of a unit test to test it?

Comment: Grails 2.4.0 -- I don't know.  I'm new to Grails and I was told to do this as an integration test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to implement the test as a unit test like this.

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
@TestFor(SimpleController)
class SimpleControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void 'test index'() {
        when:
        controller.index()

        then:
        response.redirectedUrl == '/simple/hello'
    }
}
```

Using a unit test has the advantage of speed.

Comment: there that worked!  Thank you.   Why did that work and my junit-style one didn't?   I'm curious.  thank you for that help.

Comment: Can't say. Maybe you can post all of your test code?